# Print request in httpBackend API mock module in Protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, httpbackend, e2e-testing, ngmocke2e

I run my e2e tests against a mocked API using angular service $httpBackend in protractor.

I already have the debug log of the selenium browser:

```
afterEach(function() {
  browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function(browserLog){
    if(browserLog.length) {
      for (var i = 0; i < browserLog.length; i++) {
        if( typeof browserLog[i] !== 'undefined') {
          console.log(
            JSON
            .parse(browserLog[i].message).message.parameters[0].value
          );
        }
      };
    }
  });
});
```

I'd like to print **URL** and **headers** of each request inside my httpBackend module (eg for users resourse) :

```
$httpBackend
  .whenGET(/^\/api\/users.*$/)
  .respond(function(method, url, data, headers) {
     var users = mockUserService.getData();
     console.log(url);
     console.log(headers);
     return [200, users, {}];
});
```

But nothing is logged anywhere inside the httpBackend module. It works fine when I use it in my app but not when I use it with protractor.

Is there any way to print it anywhere? Even in an output text file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`console.log()` statements are [ignored](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-hold-of-the-browsers-console) by WebDriver.
You can use `console.info()`, `console.warn()` or `console.error()` as described [here](https://ngmilk.rocks/2014/10/17/detecting-console-errors-while-testing-angularjs-with-protractor/).